# Nicomimi sensor not sending any values to bluetooth

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, bluetooth

I am trying to replicate [this project.](https://www.instructables.com/id/Gaming-With-ThoughtsMindwaves-w-Arduino/)

TL;DR for the project:

1. Hack the nicomimi toy to get the chip to send signal to HC-05 bluetooth.
2. connect a PC to a arduino leaonardo which in turn is connected to a HC-06 which receives the bluetooth signals sent by HC-05.
3. Based on the signals received program the leonardo to press the corresponding keys in the keyboard.

I did it as per the instructions and ran into a problem. I am always getting a single value in HC-06. I suspected that it might be a problem with the connection established between HC 05 to 06. So  I eliminated the middle man and directly connected the Tx pin from the nicomimi headset to the leonardo and printed whatever value the device was sending. It appears so that it is always sending a static value.

[image: Img 1][image: Img 2]
[image: Schema]
Is there a way to check if the nicomimi chip is working correctly or not. or is there any error in the circuit I have made?

Comment: To eliminate another middle man why don't you raise your query directly with the instructable people. There is an "ask question" button. Use it. I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should be raised with the "instructables" people i.e. no sign of the OP using common sense. And, if you say that they don't answer then don't use their designs.

Comment: @Andyaka I have done the same. But I thought it would be more suited here because it relates to the functioning of a single chip rather than the project as a whole.

Comment: Unless someone has done this project it is unlikely that there will be any help from members without a schematic diagram.

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks for the suggestion I have added the same